# Errors receiving emails with imaplib, from a specific inbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, office365, imaplib

When reading emails from a specific folder (Office365), the body of the message is a random long string that makes no sense.

Initially, I sent those emails to my personal mail as copy, to a specific folder. Reading from there I haven't had problems. 
But when I try to read directly from the main inbox, the messages are  long strings that makes no sense (so, I can´t parse anything)

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(SMTP_SERVER)
     mail.login(FROM_EMAIL, FROM_PWD)
     boxes = mail.list()
     mail.select('INBOX/netstatus', readonly=True) 
     (type, data) = mail.uid('SEARCH', None, '(UNSEEN)') 
     mail_ids = data[0]
     id_list = mail_ids.split()


def read_email(self, *id_list):
    id_list = list(id_list)
    for i in reversed(id_list):
        (typ, data) = mail.uid('FETCH', i, '(RFC822)')
    for response_part in data:                  
        if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
            print("Response: ",response_part)
            msg = \         email.message_from_string(response_part[1].decode('utf-8'))                                                                       

            body = ''
            email_subject = msg['subject']
            email_from = msg['from']
            email_date = msg['date']
            message= msg.get_payload().encode('utf-8')
            print(message)
```

I receive something like this when I read from my personal inbox:

> mymail:  b'Status from Device (x.x.x.x) to AnotherDevice (y.y.y.y), interface A B, in Protocol came up\r\n'

But when I read from the main inbox:

> 'QWRq4N5IGZyb20gVVREFxLXJlMSAuMTAuMjUsIDAxMDAuMTAwMS4w\r\nMDI1LjAwKSB0byBVU0FEQUxIERS4MC4xMC4xMMDAxLjAw\r\nMjUuMDQpLCBpbnZhY2UgMTAuMTA4AuMjI5IHRvIDEwLjEwLjIwLjEzMCwgaW4gSVNJUy9M\r\nZXZlbDIgd2VudCBkkNvbmZ3VyZWQgd2F0Y2hsaXN0OiI1OQ0K\r\n'

Comment: It is a base64 encoded message (although malformed). Use `message.decode("base64")` to decode.

Comment: Looks like a server-side error. This is Microsoft Exchange, you say?

Comment: You have indentation error at `for response_part ...`.

Comment: get_payload(decode=true) will cause the email library to automatically do base64 and Quoted-Printable decoding.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys.

Max, your solution worked just fine! Another day  I will try to understand why this happen only on one inbox.

Answer (score 0):

With Python3.6 or later, you can use [`EmailMessage.get_content()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.get_content) to decode the encoded content automatically.

```
import email
from email import policy

# Email based on one of the examples at https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/email.examples.html

s = """Subject: Ayons asperges pour le =?utf-8?q?d=C3=A9jeuner?=
From: =?utf-8?q?Pep=C3=A9?= Le Pew <pepe@example.com>
To: Penelope Pussycat <penelope@example.com>,
 Fabrette Pussycat <fabrette@example.com>
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
MIME-Version: 1.0

ICAgIFNhbHV0IQoKICAgIENlbGEgcmVzc2VtYmxlIMOgIHVuIGV4Y2VsbGVudCByZWNpcGllWzFd
IGTDqWpldW5lci4KCiAgICBbMV0gaHR0cDovL3d3dy55dW1tbHkuY29tL3JlY2lwZS9Sb2FzdGVk
LUFzcGFyYWd1cy1FcGljdXJpb3VzLTIwMzcxOAoKICAgIC0tUGVww6kKICAgIAo=
"""

msg = email.message_from_string(s, policy=policy.default)
print(msg.get_content())
```

Result:

```
    Salut!

    Cela ressemble à un excellent recipie[1] déjeuner.

    [1] http://www.yummly.com/recipe/Roasted-Asparagus-Epicurious-203718

    --Pepé
```

For multipart messages you need to iterate over the parts:

```
for part in msg.iter_parts():
    print(part.get_content())
```