# Python Email body content Base64 not able to decode

Tags: python, email-parsing

While am trying to parse the body of an email, the body will get as

```
VCBJTkZPUk1BVElPTjwvdGQ+Cgk8L3RyPgoJPHRyPjx0ZD4mbmJzcDs8L3RkPjwvdHI+Cgk8dHI+
```

And when I try to decode it separately, it works successfully

```
import base64
data="VCBJTkZPUk1BVElPTjwvdGQ+Cgk8L3RyPgoJPHRyPjx0ZD4mbmJzcDs8L3RkPjwvdHI+Cgk8dHI+"
print(base64.b64decode((data)))
```

Output:

```
b'T INFORMATION</td>\n\t</tr>\n\t<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>\n\t<tr>'
```

But while i tried the same in my mail parsing script, it doesnt works

```
try:
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
    mail.login(FROM_EMAIL,FROM_PWD)
    mail.select('inbox')

    type, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
    mail_ids = data[0]

    id_list = mail_ids.split()
    first_email_id = int(id_list[0])
    latest_email_id = int(id_list[-1])
    print(id_list)
    print(first_email_id)
    print(latest_email_id)
    for i in data[0].decode().split(' '):
        print(i)
        typ, data = mail.fetch(i, '(RFC822)' )
        data=(data[0][1])
        print(base64.b64decode(data))

except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

The output is getting as follows:

```
b"\r\xe9b\xbd\xea\xdeu:-\xa2|\xa9\xae\x8b^rH&j)\\\"
```

Is there any way to decode this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python email quoted-printable encoding problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040074/python-email-quoted-printable-encoding-problem)

Comment: The duplicate I've linked to features a mail whose body has been transfer-encoded with 'quoted-printable' encoding, but the same solutions work for base64.

Comment: If you want an explicitly base64 example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53877899/errors-receiving-emails-with-imaplib-from-a-specific-inbox/53896289#53896289